How to update table with values from another table not connected with the first one?
I have a table and want to replace newid() with values from another table. Here is an update statement:
UPDATE tbl1
SET tbl1.NewKey = NEWID()
FROM @List AS tbl1
WHERE tbl1.NewFlag = 1

I am going to update this table with values from my table instead of newid() :
drop TABLE if exists #tmpGUIDs
CREATE TABLE #tmpGUIDs
(
   rnum INT,
   uuid uniqueidentifier
)
-- filled here

How can I do this? As I see the problem is no keys to join these tables but here can be done something like "next value" from the tmp table

As a rule of thumb in SQL, if there not exist one or more columns in a table which provide the ordering of data, then no such ordering exists.

How do you define "next value" and why is this a temp table?

Yes, except for the rnum column. Of course that wouldn't necessarily mean there can't be gaps, say if rows got deleted and a guid shouldn't be reused.

@shawnt00 I need to do something like update t set f = newid() where .... in that case newid() provide next value every record
